# How to count same words in a string and get the index of the first word that is equal?

Tags: java, arrays

My task is to create a static method named "dupWords" that gets a strings as a parameter and returns how many times a word is at the same string. Now the catch is, that I need to return it as a Two-dimensional array, that have 2 columns and the rows will be how many different sub strings are in the string...

for example: "abcd xyz abcd abcd def xyz"

this will be the pairs [0][3] [5][2] [19][01]  the first pair means that the word "abcd" appears 3 times and state at the index 0 (and you get the rest..)

this is an image of the two-dimensional array: (the text is in hebrew but you can see the drawing)

[image]

I started something...you will probably think its way off :/ (its just some start)
I think I didn't really understand how to deal with the two-dimensional array..

```
public static int[][] dupWords (String str) {

        String [] stringArray = str.split(" ");
        int countWords = 0;
        int index = 0;
        int [][] retArr;

        for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < stringArray.length; j++) {
                if (stringArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase(stringArray[j])){
                    countWords++;
                    index = stringArray[i].indexOf(str); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help,
thankss

Comment: Just asking: Is that a picture made with a camera of your screen that shows Skitch viewing a picture made with a camera of your sheet of paper, with an arrow on top of that?

Comment: i took this picture with my iPhone (yes, skitch app) and yes its on a paper..@MartijnCourteaux

Comment: This feels like *PictureCeption* to me. But I guess that the Skitch app just makes grainy arrows?

Comment: oh yes its a caption, and then i opened it in skitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the number of unique words.

You can do it, by putting all the words from the `stringArray` to a hashmap. The hashmap will come handy later.

Create an array like that retArr = new int[unique][2];

Complete solution below (beware, I didn't even compile it!)

```
public static int[][] dupWords (String str) {

    String [] stringArray = str.split(" ");
    int countWords = 0;
    int index = 0;
    HashMap<String, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.size(); i++) {
       String s = stringArray[i];
       if (!indexMap .containsKey(s)) {
         indexMap.put(s, index);
         countMap.put(s, 1);
       }
       else {
         int cnt = countMap.get(s);
         countMap.put(s, cnt+1);
       }
       index += s.length() + 1;
    }

    int [][] retArr = new int[map.size()][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.size(); i++) {
       String s = stringArray[i];
       retArr[i][0] = indexMap.get(s);
       retArr[i][1] = countMap.get(s);
    }

    return retArr;
}
```

Now, without HashMap, or any other dynamic structure it's quite difficult to do. The easiest approach is to create a bigger than necessary array and at the end trim it. This could look like this.

```
public static int[][] dupWords (String str) {

    String [] stringArray = str.split(" ");
    int countWords = 0;
    int index = 0;

    int [][] retArr = new int[stringArray.size()][2];

    int uniqeWords = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.size(); i++) {
       String s = stringArray[i];
       if (s != null) {
         retArr[uniqueWords][0] = str.indexOf(s);
         int cnt = 1;
         for (int j = i + 1; j < stringArray.size(); j++) {
           if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(stringArray[j])) {
             stringArray[j] = null;
             cnt++;
           }
         }
         retArr[uniqueWords][1] = cnt;
         uniqueWords++;
       }
    }

    int[][] newRetArr = new int[uniqueWords][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < uniqueWords; i++) {
      newRetArr[i][0] = retArr[i][0];
      newRetArr[i][1] = retArr[i][1];
    }

    return newRetArr;
}
```

Comment: but then i will create new array for each word...this is what i suppose to do?

Comment: no, before the loop you already have, you have to check the number of unique words, then create the array, then run your loop

Comment: we didn't learn HashSet and this kind of for(String str : stringArray) yet in class...we still use the more basic stuff

Comment: this is how i counted the words, http://d.pr/i/5eRQ its a link to droplr, don't worry :)

Comment: Unfortunately your code for counting unique words is wrong. First of all, don't compare string with == or != use equals instead. Secondly, you count something else than number of unique words, the two loops won't give you the result you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) to store the count and first index of each unique word.

```
Map<String, Map<String, int>> uniqueWords = new HashMap<>();
```

Then Change your loop through `stringArray` to only use the first outer loop. You don't need the inner loop.

In each iteration through stringArray, do

```
if(!uniqueWords.get(stringArray[i])) {
    uniqueWords.put(stringArray[i], new HashMap<String, int>());
    uniqueWords.get(stringArray[i]).put("Count", 0);
    uniqueWords.get(stringArray[i]).put("Index", str.indexOf(stringArray[i]));
}

uniqueWords.get(stringArray[i]).get("Count")++;
```

You can then use the uniqueWords map to build your return array. I'll leave that for you to code.

Comment: rather than bring the code down to a lower level, what say we elevate your understanding of the code to a higher level? My original answer linked the `HashMap` reference to the java class definition page. I've edited it so that it now links to the oracle tutorials page for the `Map` interface.

Comment: You can think of a HashMap as a unique "Associative Array" on steroids. An associative array is just a regular array that uses String values as it's key rather than integer indexes. So, rather than `array[0]`, `array[1]`, ... you would access an associative array as `array['keyvaluea']`, `array['keyvalueb']`, ... The difference is, a HashMap can have any primitive data type as it's key, not just a string. Whatever you specify in the `<KeyType, ValueType>` argument.